# FLUTTER: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: File format not recognised

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-test

One moment the project was running fine but when i tried to debug the code again i got this error.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A515F in debug mode...                          lib\main.dart:1
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: File format not recognised

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run
`flutter clean`
followed by
`flutter pub get`
then
`flutter run`

Comment: tried same issue